# Oracle Invalid Identifier ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting this error trying to run this simple Join.....

```
SELECT docregitem.reviewdate, docregitem.nclient, client.name
FROM docregitem, client
     INNER JOIN client
      ON docregitem.nclient = client.nclient

ORA-00904: "DOCREGITEM"."NCLIENT": invalid identifier
```

I can do a select and all the columns are present and correct...

Comment: show table structure of docregitem.  It really looks like either the table is not correctly named or the column is.  `Select * from all_tab_Cols where table_Name = 'DOCREGITEM' and column_Name = 'NCCLIENT'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT dr.reviewdate, dr.nclient, c.name
FROM docregitem dr INNER JOIN
     client c
     ON dr.nclient = c.nclient;
```

Your `from` clause has a comma in it.  This is a lot like a `cross join`, but it affects the columns.  These are not known in the `on` clause, which is what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT docregitem.reviewdate, docregitem.nclient, client.name
FROM docregitem
INNER JOIN client
ON docregitem.nclient = client.nclient
```

you try this one as you used client table twice one with simple join and other with inner join without giving the alias name to the table so the compiler is confused in selecting and comparing column from client table.